# SQL Query to fetch record from 1 tables based on 2 records in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to write a query which will display the top 25 game_id which are under specific genre.
Database table is like

```
| id | genre_id | game_id | is_primary |
----------------------------------------
  1    6000       12345      0
  2    6007       12345      1
  3    6000       23492      0
  4    6007       82837      1
----------------------------------------
```

Here you can see that record 1 and 2 have same game_id for both is_primary = 0 and 1. What i have to do is to execute a query having both the genre_id with me and i have to fetch the game_id which falls under both. Means game_id which have 6000 as genre_id and is_primary=0 and 6007 as genre_id with is_primary=1.

Searched on net but no success.

I tried this query

```
 SELECT game_id FROM table_name WHERE 
(SELECT game_id FROM table_name WHERE genre_id=6000 AND is_primary=0) 
AND ganre_id=6007 AND is_primary=1;
```

But this query is giving error as `Subquery returns more than one value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query (UPDATED)

```
SELECT game_id FROM table_name WHERE game_id IN(SELECT game_id FROM table_name WHERE genre_id=6000 AND is_primary=0)
 AND ( ganre_id=6007 AND is_primary=1);
```

Comment: Hey Thanks alot! It was so easy and i was trying it from much more complex way. I tried using above query too but with AND instead of OR.

Answer (score 1):

[`JOIN` performs much better than subqueries](http://www.codersrevolution.com/index.cfm/2008/7/31/MySQL-performance-INNER-JOIN-vs-subselect):

```
SELECT t1.game_id
FROM table_name t1
JOIN table_name t2 ON (t1.game_id = t2.game_id AND t2.genre_id = 6000 AND t2.is_primary = 0)
WHERE (t1.genre_id = 6007 AND t1.is_primary = 1)
```